# Able to re-install Ubuntu 10.04 after recent install?

Tags: partitioning, ubuntu-10.04, multi-boot, gparted, easybcd

I just performed a triple partition involving Windows XP, Windows 7, and Ubuntu 10.04. I installed them in that order. However, I now realize that I would like to boot using Windows Boot Manager so I can hopefully retain access to the Windows XP Recovery Console. I don't know if it will be successful, but I'd like to try.

Anyway, as I just installed Ubuntu and used GParted to resize the partitions, will I be able to just boot from the Ubuntu Live CD and then reinstall Ubuntu again? This way, I can install GRUB on the Ubuntu partition using EasyBCD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that will be the best/easiest way to go. If you will like to use windows mbr then use windows 7, bcdedit.

Just make sure you install ubuntu in your right partition and also mbr as the first sector in your hdd.